# Incrementing a number at the end of string

Tags: python, regex, string, list

I am trying to solve a problem which says, to add **1** at the end of a *string*.
Which means:

1.**abcd12** will become: **abcd13**

2.**abcd099** will become **abcd100**

3.**abcd01** will become **abcd02**

4.**ddh^add@2204** will become **ddh^add@2205**

My code:

```
import re
def increment_string(strng):
    regex = re.compile(r'[0-9]')
    match = regex.findall(strng)
    
    nums = ''.join(match[-3:])
    
    add = int(nums)+1
    print(strng+str(add))
increment_string("abcd99")
```

The code gives me this Output: **abcd099100** and I don't know how to solve it:

Comment: Well, your code never attempts to _replace_ the old number with the new one - it just appends the new number to the string. So, the way to solve this is to actually perform the replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match all digits at the end of string with `[0-9]+$` and use `re.sub` with a callable as the replacement argument:

```py
import re
def increment_string(strng):
    return re.sub(r'[0-9]+$', lambda x: f"{str(int(x.group())+1).zfill(len(x.group()))}", strng)

print(increment_string("abcd99"))
# => abcd100
print(increment_string("abcd099"))
# => abcd100
print(increment_string("abcd001"))
# => abcd002
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/4GLKUM)

Comment: abcd should equal abcd1

Comment: @AyushKumar But you [say](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64663411/3832970) "**foobar00** should become **foobar01**". I understand you need to keep the amount of digits.

Comment: I just had to use `if else` statements to improve my code. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Replace the old number with `''`:

```
import re


def increment_string(strng):
    regex = re.compile(r'[0-9]')
    match = regex.findall(strng)

    nums = ''.join(match[-3:])
    strng = strng.replace(nums, '')
    add = int(nums) + 1

    print(strng + str(add))


increment_string("abcd99")
```

Output:

```
abcd100
```