# Invalid value after matching string using regex

Tags: python, regex, string, list

I am trying to match strings with an addition of 1 at the end of it and my code gives me this problem:

1. **abcd01** should become **abcde02** but my code gives me this output: **abcde2**
2. **foobar00** should become **foobar01** but my code gives me this output: **foobar1**
3. **foobar001** should become **foobar002**
4. **foobar1** should become **foobar2**
   My code:

```
def increment_string(strng):
    regex = re.compile(r'[0-9]')
    match = regex.findall(strng)
    
    nums = ''.join(match[-3:])
    strng = strng.replace(nums,'')
    add = int(nums)+1
    print(strng+str(add))
```

Comment: See the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/64632667/3832970

Answer (score 0):

Count the number of zeros until the first number and add them to the number at last. Here is the full code:

```
def increment_string(strng):
    regex = re.compile(r'[0-9]')
    match = regex.findall(strng)

    nums = ''.join(match[-3:])
    strng = strng.replace(nums, '')
    if len(nums) > 0:
        add = int(nums) + 1
        zeros = 0
        for digit in str(nums[:-1]):
            if digit == "0":
                zeros += 1
            else:
                break
        zeros -= len(str(add)) - len(str(add-1))
        add = ''.join(["0" for x in range(zeros)]) + str(add)
    else:
        add = "1"
    print(strng + add)
```

Output:

```
abcd02
```

For `foobar00`:

```
increment_string('foobar00')
```

Output:

```
foobar01
```

For `foobar002`:

```
increment_string('foobar002')
```

Output:

```
foobar003
```

For `abcd`:

```
increment_string('abcd')
```

Output:

```
abcd1
```

Comment: Can you explain `"0" + str(add) if len(str(add)) == 1 else str(add)` a bit.

Comment: It is actually simple. It converts `add` to an `str` and adds `0` before it if the length of `add` is 1 (i.e `add` only has 1 digit). Else, it just converts `add` to an `str`. This is a shorthand of this: `if len(str(add)) == 1:        add = "0" + str(add)       else:       add = str(add)`

Comment: If my ans has helped u, pls upvote my ans and accept it as the best ans. Thanks!

Comment: foobar001 should equal foobar002 and foobar1 should equal foobar2

Comment: Oh ok. I will update my ans in 2 min.

Comment: Check out my latest edit.

Comment: abcd should become abcd1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224037/discussion-between-sushil-and-ayush-kumar).

Comment: Leave i got the anwer from @Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: Giving you an upvote because your code is helpful too. Thanks for your valueable time.